# How to get RMSE value from GA hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: r, hyperparameters

I found R code for hyperparameter tuning using GA. The following is the code, but it does not show the expected results, which will be the prediction accuracy? I have mentioned the output it produces at the end of the question but I expected an output RMSE values like, 0.44, 0.23, 0.1 etc

The code is as follows:

```
d=readARFF("soft.arff")
index <- createDataPartition(d$Effort, p = .70,list = FALSE)
tr <- d[index, ]
ts <- d[-index, ] 
svm_fit <- function(x) {
  mod <- train(Rank ~ ., data = tr,
               method = "svmRadial",
               preProc = c("center", "scale"),
               trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"),
               tuneGrid = data.frame(C = 2^x[1], sigma = exp(x[2])))
  -getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainRMSE"]
}

svm_ga_obj <- GA::ga(type = "real-valued", 

                            fitness = svm_fit,              

                                  min = c(-5, -5), 
                                  max = c(5, 0), 
                                  popSize = 50, 
                                  maxiter = 2,
                                  seed = 16478,
                                  keepBest = TRUE,
                                  monitor = NULL,
                                  elitism = 2)

summary(svm_ga_obj)
```

The code does not give error and executed successfully but instead of RMSE value, it shows the following output when I execute a `summary(svm_ga_obj)`.

```
GA settings: 
Type                  =  real-valued 
Population size       =  50 
Number of generations =  2 
Elitism               =  2 
Crossover probability =  0.8 
Mutation probability  =  0.1 
Search domain = 
      x1 x2
lower -5 -5
upper  5  0

GA results: 
Iterations             = 2 
Fitness function value = -6309.072 
Solution = 
          x1        x2
[1,] 4.80478 -4.202595
```

What is the problem and how I can get the value of RMSE?

Comment: Please include the packages you're using for this code to run

Comment: library(e1071)
library(mlr)
library(caret), library(GA), library(farff)